# $\Bbb Q(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})\subset \Bbb R$?

Tags: trigonometry, field-theory, galois-theory, real-numbers

How do I show $\Bbb Q(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})\subset \Bbb R$? Where $\zeta$ is an 11th root of unity.

I can see that $\Bbb Q(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})=\Bbb Q(2\cos(2\pi/11))$, and I have shown that $[\Bbb Q(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}):\Bbb Q]=5$ but there are a few things confusing me.

How do I show that this is within the reals? Surely $\cos(2\pi/11)$ is within the reals, but how do I ensure the other $4$ roots are?

Comment: Ir $z$ is real then $\mathbb Q[z]$ is real.

Comment: What do you mean "the other four roots?" What other four roots? Roots of what? $\mathbb Q[z]$ is not defined in terms of other roots. If $z$ is real, then $\mathbb Q[z]$ is real. It is true that in this case, the minimal polynomial for $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ has all real roots, but that is not what it means for $\mathbb Q[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $[\Bbb Q(\zeta + \zeta^{-1}:\Bbb Q]=5$ so then $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ has a 5th degree minimal polynomial. The minimal polynomial is $x^5+x^4-4x^3-3x^2+3x+1$ but I want to understand without looking at it from that perspective\

Comment: But why do you think all the roots have to be real for $\mathbb Q[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]\subseteq \mathbb R$? In general, that is not true. You asked why $\mathbb Q[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]\subseteq \mathbb R$, not why all the roots of the minimal polynomial are real. Those are different questions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay I think I have condensed my confusion to the following:

1) Adjoining a root $\alpha$ to $\Bbb Q$, which has minimal polynomial $f$, means that $f$ splits in $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$?

2) Adjoining $\alpha$ to $\Bbb Q$ gives a $\Bbb Q$-vectorspace, that consists of basis $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\cdots\}$, where at some point for a finite extension, $\alpha^n=1$?

3) If my $\Bbb Q$-vectorspace basis is real in all components, any element in that basis must be real?

Comment: No. For example: $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is of degree $3$ over $\mathbb Q$, and does not split the minimal polynomial $x^3-2$. In general, the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ does not split into linear factors in $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$. The "splitting field" for $x^3-2$ is of dimension $6$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: (2) It is most certainly not true that $\alpha^n=1$ for some $n$. If $\alpha$ is algebraic, then $\alpha^n$ is some linear combination of lower powers of $\alpha$, so $\alpha^0,\alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^{n-1}$ is a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$. But we don't have $\alpha^n=1$.

Comment: You've shown that your $\alpha$ has the property that $\alpha^5=-\alpha^4+4\alpha^3+3\alpha^2-3\alpha-1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Wow you are amazing, thank you for being so persistent, that clears up my confusions tremendously !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|z|=1$ then $z+\frac{1}{z}=z+\overline{z}=2\mathrm{Re}(z)$.

In general, if $\alpha$ is real then $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ is a subset of the reals.

Comment: How do I show the latter statement is true? I haven't done complex analysis, just algebra.

Comment: How do you define $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$? This has nothing to do with complex analysis. What is $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$? Are all of its elements real if $\alpha$ is real?

Comment: I mean I think I am mainly confused since normally I can see the basis as a $\Bbb Q$-vectorspace. But in this case, I can't.

Comment: Is $\Bbb Q[\alpha] = \{ a+b\cos(2\pi /11)+c\cos(2\pi /11)^2+d\cos(2\pi /11)^3+e \cos(2\pi /11)^4\}$?

Comment: It is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, it's just that the real numbers are much bigger than we expect. That's the power of the general idea of a vector space. In fact, $\mathbb Q[\zeta]$ is a vector space of dimenions $n$ over $\mathbb Q$, but we don't have a problem with that, even though it is a plane, which is $2$-dimensional? Same thing happens in the reals.

Comment: As for your second question, $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ is not defined as such, and I gave you no specific $\alpha$, so what are you talking about? What is $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ in general. What is $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$? $\mathbb Q[\pi]$?

Comment: Sorry I treated $\alpha = \zeta + \zeta^{-1}$

Comment: @Galois: $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ consists of all the numbers that are the value of a _rational_ polynomial evaluated at $\alpha$. Those numbers are always real -- a polynomial with real coefficients always evaluates to a real number when you plug a real number in for the variable.

Comment: But answer the general question first, and you'll see how it applies and is about all real numbers.

Comment: $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$, $\Bbb Q[\pi] = \{a+b\pi + c\pi^2+\cdots,a,b,c,\cdots \in \Bbb Q\}$? If that is right, I can see they are both a subset of $\Bbb R$

Comment: Where the latter is an infinite extension. Or I am completely confused, and we only gain other roots of the minimal polynomial of $\pi$

Comment: @Galois: $\mathbb Q[\pi]$ is not even a field, and thus not a fields extension, finite or infinite. It does consist of the elements you wrote, though, if interpreted properly: only _finite_ rational combinations of powers of $\pi$ are there.

Comment: The key is that in $\mathbb Q[\pi]$, only finitely many of the coefficients are allowed to be non-zero. So, what is a basis of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$? A basis of the infinite-dimensional $\mathbb Q[\pi]$? A general $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is a algebraic of degree $k$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Can you clarify the part after ":" how could there only be a finite number of powers of $\pi$?

at ThomasAndrews The basii are $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$, for the pi one no idea pending Henning's response, and $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\cdots,\alpha^{k-1}\}$ I would think?

Comment: @GaloisintheField From your question, you seem to think $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ has something to do with "other roots." Other roots of *what*? $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ is not defined in terms of roots of anything. You can show that the minimal polynomial for this $\alpha$ splits so that all roots are in the field. The minimal polynomial, in this case, is some variant of a Chebyshev polynomial.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh I just understood your last comment, it's not a field, it's a polynomial ring firstly, and secondly, any arbitrary element is a finite rational combination of powers of $\pi$, not an infinite string, which wouldn't make sense, yep. Oh and Thomas was saying the same thing, doh.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is that for $z$ on the unit circle, $1/z=\overline z$.